# Do sum rules for spectral function always hold?

Tags: condensed-matter, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory, greens-functions, non-perturbative

In condensed matter physics, we can define the spectral function as
$$
A_{\alpha}(\omega) = -\frac{1}{\pi}\mathrm{Im}G_{\alpha}^R (\omega)
$$
It can be shown that this quantity satisfies the sum rule:
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}A_{\alpha}(\omega) =1
\end{equation}
This is a non-perturbative result that always needs to hold. However, in practice, the retarded Green function $G_\alpha^R(\omega)$ is almost never evaluated exactly. We can only approximate it (usually using the Dyson series). For example, if we calculate the self-energy using the perturbation theory to a given order, then we can express the spectral function as:
$$
A_{\mathbf k} (\omega) = \frac{-\frac{1}{\pi}\mathrm{Im}\Sigma_{\mathbf k}(\omega)}
{\left[\omega - (\epsilon_{\mathbf k }- \mu) - \mathrm{Re}\Sigma_{\mathrm{k}}(\omega)\right]^2 + \left[ \mathrm{Im}\Sigma_{\mathbf k}(\omega) \right]^2}
$$
This is also an approximate result, since the self-energy is also an approximation. Do sum rules still need to hold for this, approximate spectral function?